# scrollable table without effecting table alignment

Tags: jquery, html

Some one please help me to make a below table as scrollable without effecting already defined style. I have tried with overflow= auto by defining tbody as display block. but no luck because its changing the width of the table and getting some mis alignment of cell header and body also.

```js
$.post('geterpitem', {
      grn: $('#grn').val()
    }, function(responseJson) {
      if (responseJson.length != null) {
        var $tbl = $("#itemtable");
        $tbody = $tbl.find('tbody');
        $tbl.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
        var i = 1;
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
          var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
          rowNew.children().eq(0).append(i);
          rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['itemcode']);
          rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['itemname']);
          rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['receivedqty']);
          rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text"  id="inspdate"/>');
          rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<input type="text"  id="accqty" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"/>');
          rowNew.children().eq(6).html('<input type="text"  id="rejqty" class="reject"/>');
          rowNew.children().eq(7).html('<input type="text"  id="rema"/>');
          rowNew.appendTo($tbody);
          i++;
        });
      }
```

```css
/* table-itemtable styles */

.t1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.t1 th {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.t1 tr {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="itemtable" class="t1" border="1px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> SLno</th>
      <th>Item code</th>
      <th>Item name</th>
      <th>Received qty</th>
      <th>Insp Date</th>
      <th>Accepted qty</th>
      <th>Rejected qty</th>
      <th>Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: U need to wrap your table in div and set that div overflow:auto and any height that you want. Then your table will be scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below CSS,

```
tbody {
    display: block;
    height: 100px;     /* Let it for 100px */
    overflow: auto;    /* Trigger scroll   */
    width: 100%;
}
```